# Can autopilot use an existing Ceph cluster?

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot, ceph

If I already have an existing Ceph cluster, can Autopilot build an OpenStack cloud that makes use of it? Or does Autopilot want to set the whole thing up itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autopilot uses a reference architecture that co-locates compute (Nova) and storage (Ceph OSD) on the same nodes. As a result, consuming an external storage cluster is not necessary.

Comment: Right, thanks. So it sounds like it's not suitable for an environment with an existing Ceph cluster an nodes ready to deploy OpenStack on that don't have large amounts of storage in them?

Comment: I think you may be able to drop into the Juju environment that Autopilot uses and re-configure the cloud to point to your external cluster with a few commands.